# ASP.NET simple image display

Tags: asp.net, image, visual-studio-2012

I have a simple problem where the image(stored in the website's root folder), is being displayed in visual studio's design view but not when i run it in the browser.
Following is my code.
the text portion is not getting displayed either.

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
   <div>
        <h2 style="color:gray; text-align: center;">
            <br />
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" AlternateText="placement portal logo" Height="100px" ImageUrl="~/1369497013.png" Width="100px" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" />
           <br /> Placement<br />
            Cell
        </h2>
        </div>
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

   </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are not giving path correctly and also image is present in picture box also use `~\`  or  `..\` before giving path

Comment: check my answer and markup and correct also

Answer (score 0):

3 ways

1-use CSS to give path but this will not work in your case

2-use html to give path harrdcoded thing always works there

3-use c# to give path and remember to
give path accurratly using

```
 ../root/image1.png
```

or

```
 ~/root/image1.png
```